# Supporting multiple iOS versions: checking for extern CFTypeRef symbols

Tags: ios

I'm working on an app that supports iOS 6 and iOS 7, and I want to support iCloud Keychain sync if the feature is available (iOS 7.0.3 and up). Looking at Security/SecItem.h there are the following entries:

```
extern CFTypeRef kSecAttrSynchronizable
    __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_9, __IPHONE_7_0);
extern CFTypeRef kSecAttrSynchronizableAny
    __OSX_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_9, __IPHONE_7_0);
```

In the past, I've checked that an ObjC symbol's address is not `NULL`, and so `CFTypeRef` shouldn't work any differently (right?!). So, let's go for it:

```
if (&kSecAttrSynchronizable != NULL) {
    // iCloud Keychain syncing code
}
else {
    // We're in iOS 6 territory
}
```

Build it a run on my iOS 6.1.3 device and ... the check is successful - `kSecAttrSynchronizable` exists. What? How is this possible? The two possibilities that come to mind are:

1. My assumptions about checking for symbols is horribly wrong (high probability)
2. Apple actually has `kSecAttrSynchronizable` defined (privately?) in versions prior to iOS 7.0.3 (possible but not likely)

So what's going on here?

Comment: It's not unprecedented that some classes, methods, or other symbols went from private to public in newer versions of iOS. So options 2 is a good possibility.

Comment: @rmaddy how would I confirm this? But, more important would your recommendation be "ship it" because I've done the best to curtail Very Bad Things™ given the circumstances? (I'm setting up the keychain attributes dictionary conditionally)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the droids I was looking for:

```
if (&kSecAttrSynchronizable != NULL && &kSecAttrSynchronizableAny != NULL)
```

The `kSecAttrSynchronizable` external symbol is available in iOS 6.1.3, but the `kSecAttrSynchronizableAny` symbol is not. It is probably safe to only check for the latter, but future-me will think it is unclear why I am checking for the value and not the key.